# How to read sub node values from xml file

Tags: c#, .net, xml

Below is the XML sample. 'file' is the repeated node. Need to read 'filename' and 'sftp1' ,'sftp2','sftp3' elements values from 'sftp'. we need to repeat the same for each 'file' Node.

```css
<FTPLocations>
  <file>
    <filedetails>
      <filename>sample.txt</filename>
    </filedetails>
    <sftp>
      <sftp1>
        <sftp-username>UN</sftp-username>
        <sftp-password>PW</sftp-password>
        <sftp-host>ipaddress</sftp-host>           
        <sftp-path>path</sftp-path>
      </sftp1>
      <sftp2>
        <sftp-username>UN</sftp-username>
        <sftp-password>PW</sftp-password>
        <sftp-host>ipaddress</sftp-host>            
        <sftp-path>path</sftp-path>
      </sftp2>
      <sftp3>
        <sftp-username>UN</sftp-username>
        <sftp-password>PW</sftp-password>
        <sftp-host>ipaddress</sftp-host>           
        <sftp-path>path</sftp-path>
      </sftp3>
    </sftp>   
  </file>
  <file>
    <filedetails>
      <filename>sample.txt</filename>
    </filedetails>
    <sftp>
      <sftp1>
        <sftp-username>UN</sftp-username>
        <sftp-password>PW</sftp-password>
        <sftp-host>ipaddress</sftp-host>           
        <sftp-path>path</sftp-path>
      </sftp1>
      <sftp2>
        <sftp-username>UN</sftp-username>
        <sftp-password>PW</sftp-password>
        <sftp-host>ipaddress</sftp-host>            
        <sftp-path>path</sftp-path>
      </sftp2>
      <sftp3>
        <sftp-username>UN</sftp-username>
        <sftp-password>PW</sftp-password>
        <sftp-host>ipaddress</sftp-host>           
        <sftp-path>path</sftp-path>
      </sftp3>
    </sftp>   
  </file>        
</FTPLocations>
```

Please suggest me how I can achieve this using C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access elements of your XML using following code:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load("YOUR_PATH_TO_XML");
//for sftp1
XmlNodeList sftp1_hd = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("sftp1");
foreach (XmlNode sftp1_node in sftp1_hd)
{
  foreach (XmlNode sftp1_child_nodes in sftp1_node.ChildNodes)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(sftp1_child_nodes.LocalName);
    Console.WriteLine(sftp1_child_nodes.InnerText);
  }

}

//for sftp2
XmlNodeList sftp2_hd = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("sftp2");
foreach (XmlNode sftp2_node in sftp2_hd)
{
  foreach (XmlNode sftp2_child_nodes in sftp2_node.ChildNodes)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(sftp2_child_nodes.LocalName);
    Console.WriteLine(sftp2_child_nodes.InnerText);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try xml linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication47
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            var results = doc.Descendants("sftp").Elements().Select(x => new
            {
                name = x.Name.LocalName,
                username = (string)x.Element("sftp-username"),
                password = (string)x.Element("sftp-password"),
                host = (string)x.Element("sftp-ipaddress"),
                path = (string)x.Element("sftp-path")
            }).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```